# why I can view a page in browser but can download it with code using URL

Tags: python, request

I tried to use the `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` modules to download a page from `google.scholar.com`. The url is [https://scholar.google.com/citations?mauthors=computer+science&hl=en&view_op=search_authors](https://scholar.google.com/citations?mauthors=computer%20science&hl=en&view_op=search_authors). When I copy the url to Chrome, I can view the page. But if I try to download it with `requests`, it shows me `404 NOT FOUND error`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport"/>
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
<style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
</head><body><a href="//www.google.com/"><span aria-label="Google" id="logo"></span></a>
<p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
</p><p>The requested URL <code>/citations</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
</p></body></html>
```

The script, except for the header (because it was too long), to download the page is

```
url = "https://scholar.google.com/citations?mauthors=computer+science&hl=en&view_op=search_authors"
for i in range(1200):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    print soup
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Python` you can do something like this using `BeautifulSoup` and `urllib2`:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

url = "https://scholar.google.com/citations?mauthors=computer%20science&hl=en&view_op=search_authors"

def load_url(url):
    request = Request(url)
    # Add your header here
    request.add_header('Referer', 'python.org')
    # Note here:
    # The charset used in your current website is: 'iso-8859-1'
    # data = urlopen(request).read().decode("iso-8859-1")
    data = urlopen(request).read()

    return soup(data, "lxml")


data = load_url(url)
m = data.findAll("h3", {"class": "gsc_1usr_name"})
for k in m:
    print k.get_text()
```

Otherwise, if you are using `Python3` you can do something like this using `BeautifulSoup` and `urllib.request`:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://scholar.google.com/citations?mauthors=computer%20science&hl=en&view_op=search_authors"

def load_url(url):
    request = Request(url)
    # Add headers
    request.add_header('Referer', 'python.org')

    with urlopen(request) as f:
        # The charset used
        # charset = f.info().get_content_charset()
        # Debug
        # print("The current charset is:", charset)
        data = f.read()

    return soup(data, 'lxml')

data = load_url(url)
m = data.findAll("h3", {"class": "gsc_1usr_name"})
for k in m:
    print(k.get_text())
```

Output (for both codes using `Python` and `Python3`):

```
Herbert Simon
Geoffrey Hinton
William H. Press
Jiawei Han
Stephen Boyd
anupam gupta
David S. Johnson
Scott Shenker
Jeffrey Ullman
Deborah Estrin
```

Comment: Hi, do you get blocked? I try to change User-Agent and add some stuff into header but I still got blocked after 1 min

Comment: No, i didn't get blocked. Everything seems fine to me. Can you try again and paste the error you had ?

Comment: They return a document with note that they think it is an unusual request. So I was blocked. My friend send a random timeout between 10-20s. After 10mins, he was also blocked... But I do check your code. If you run it for 1000 times, it will happen

Comment: Ok. I'll test my asnwer with a large requests and i'll leave my comment later.

Answer (score 0):

Google will block your request because it's seen as not being from a browser. An alternative to use instead would be curl. If you wanted to use it within a Python script, you can use the following code.

```
import os

html_content = os.popen('curl https://scholar.google.com/citations?mauthors=computer%20science&hl=en&view_op=search_authors').read()
```